Automatic declaration of module using tsconfig
I only have .ts files in my project and all my .d.ts files are generated automatically as I have "declaration": true in my tsconfig.json.
How can I have the following generated automatically by the TS compiler?
declare module "foo" {
    export bar;
}

I need this so I can import bar like this:
import { bar } from "foo";

Also, if I simply export bar like this
export { bar }

I have to provide relative path of the file so my IDE can detect where it is but then Node complains Error: Cannot find module when I run my application.
